# Alternate for making such a thing work in perl : `for(10..0)`

Tags: perl, for-loop

This doesn't work in perl: `for(10 .. 0)` It essentially doesn't loop even once, because it checks that `10>0` initially.

Any alternate shorthand for creating a decreasing iterating `for` loop?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
for (reverse 0 .. 10) {
  say $_;
}
```

Use the [`reverse` function](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/reverse.html).

Unfortunately, this forces evaluation of the range to a list, so this uses more memory than the loop without `reverse`.

Comment: memory isn't a problem. I was trying to shed some characters using this while golfing, but it turns out to use the same no.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure brevity is a great criteria for doing this, but you don't need the `map` in the inverting solution, nor `reverse` in the reversing one:

```
# By Inverting without map, one of:
for(-10..0){$_=-$_;say}
for(-10..0){$_*=-1;say}
# Compare to similar length with map:
for(map-$_,-10..0){say}

# Can just use -$_ where $_ is used, if $_ is used < 6 times; that's shorter.
for(-10..0){say-$_}

# By Reversing without reverse (in a sub; in main use @ARGV or @l=...=pop@l)
@_=0..10;while($_=pop){say}

# More Pop Alternatives
for(@_=0..10;$_=pop;say){}
@_=0..10;for(;$_=pop;){say}
@_=0..10;do{say$_=pop}while$_
($_,@_)=(10,0..9);do{say}while($_=pop)
# Though, yeah, it's shorter with reverse
for(reverse 0..10){say}
```

Comment: The second one looks like the best option for golfing. Unfortunately, I don't remember the entire code for which I asked the question so I can never know which of your suggestions is best.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (map -$_,-10..0) { ... }
for (map 10-$_,0..10) { ... }
```

If any part of the range is negative, then the first one is shorter than using `reverse`.

Comment: How is the first one shorter than using `reverse`, it is one char longer(In my case 2 chars because I don't start with a 0 in my loop :/)

Comment: Miscounted. They are the same size for a range like `M..-N` (`reverse-N..M` vs `map-$_,-M..N`) but two chars shorter for a negative range like `-M..-N`.