# Range operator decrementing from largest to smallest: 10..1

Tags: perl

Perl has a range operator, which when used in a `foreach` loop, does not create a temporary array:

```
foreach (1 .. 1_000_000) {
    # code
}
```

If the first integer is smaller than the second integer, then no iterations are run:

```
foreach (1_000_000 .. 1) {
    # code here never runs
}
```

I could use the `reverse` built-in, but would this keep the optimisation of not creating a temporary array?

```
foreach (reverse 1 .. 1_000_000) {
    # code
}
```

Is there a way that's as pretty and fast as the range operator for decreasing numbers, rather than increasing ones?

Comment: For reverse see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18539244/728795). In short no, there is no optimization when using reverse range

Comment: @Andrei: Thanks! I've marked my question as a duplicate of that one.

Comment: I hesitated to do the same, because strictly speaking your question is a bit different

Comment: `for (reverse EXPR..EXPR)` flattens. `for (reverse CONST..CONST)` flattens at compile-time! [Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25214138/prove-that-using-a-range-operator-in-a-loop-does-not-use-additional-memory/25214988#25214988)

Answer (score 3):

Non pretty solution,

```
for (my $i=1_000_000; $i >= 1; $i--) {

   print "$i\n";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You *could* just subtract the number you've got from one more than the top of the range:

```
foreach (1 .. 1_000_000) {
    my $n = 1_000_001 - $_;
    ...
}
```

and

```
for (-1_000_000 .. -1) {
    my $n = -$_;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Without repetition: `for (-1_000_000 .. -1) { my $n = -$_; ... }`

Comment: @ikegami nice variant :)

Answer (score 3):

While `for` is nice, `while` might be better suited.

```
my $n = 1_000_000;
while ($n >= 1) {
    ...
} continue {  # continue block will always be called, even if next is used
    $n--;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps `continue { $n-- }`

Comment: That's a good idea, it prevents `next` statements from creating infinite loops, such as with a loop condition `next if $n == 12` before the incrementation.

Comment: what if instead of a `continue` block you just set `$n` one greater and decremented it in the `while` statement?  `my$n=1000001;while(--$n>=1){...}`